# Descriptive statistics, percentage of values in interval

Tags: statistics, terminology, descriptive-statistics

I have a list of values representing estimation errors, like `{ 1, 3, 7, 16, 5, 4, 3, 1 }`. Now I determine the percentage of estimations below/equal a specified error threshold, for example `4`; in this case `5 / 8 = 0.625`.

Straightforward so far. My question is: How is this value/calculation/function called in statistics terminology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) was what I was looking for: Empirical distribution function.